# Azure Data Factory - Pagination

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-data-factory

Does anyone know how to handle pagination in Azure Data Factory when the response of the REST API isn't in the form of a next URL?

The JSON that is returned contains the following attributes:
"Skip": 0,
"Take": 100,
"TotalNumberOfRecords": 135,

TotalNumberOfRecords is the records that are present when calling the API. Yet the API always returns a maximum of 100 records.

So my next call I should add two query parameters: Skip and Take, with respectively the values 100 and 35.

Could anyone help me out to obtain this with the Pagination rules of the Copy data task in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Have you checked out the [range option in pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-1-variables-in-queryparameters) of ADF?

Answer (score 2):

Data factory has **pagination option: Range**!

You can create a variable such as "offset" in AbsoluteUrl and establish the range rule in pagination rules if you wish to make several sequence requests with that variable in a range. `offset` is such a value that will increase by certain amount which set by us.

**Example:**

[image]

Be sure to take note of the {offset} that I put to the relative URL. By using the same-named pagination rule, this is filled in. as your page size is 100 set 100 in offset to make several sequence requests.
[image]

***Reference:*** [pagination support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support).

Comment: I want to add that this answer helped me solve pagination for a GET response that doesn't contain any pagination helpers. My API source does take page as a parameter though. Following your advice, I entered "?page={pg}" as the Relative URL and created "page" as a parameter in the dataset properties. Then, I referenced {pg} in the AbsoluteUrl pagination rule with a Range of 1 to 100 (more pages than I needed). I added an EndCondition that would stop requests when the response array was empty. This functionally creates a loop, which terminates when there is no data returned. Works like a charm!