# Azure Data Factory: How to pull ALL data from REST API with JSON Pagination and copy into BLOB storage

Tags: json, azure, api, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline with a series of copy activities, to copy JSON data from a REST API into blob files. The data is heavily paginated and I need the copy activity to pull ALL of the data from ALL of the pages. Do I need to use a 'forEach' activity to achieve this? Could someone please help me configure this?

This is what the pipeline looks like:
[image]

```
{
    "count": 216,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603444"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603297"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603298"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603445"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "16407315"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18636176"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18588630"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18588941"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603301"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603302"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603303"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18588634"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18722305"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603446"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18604710"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18624916"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18625925"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603447"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603448"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603305"
        }
    ],
    "users": {
        "18603444": {
            "full_name": "",
            "photo_path": "",
            "email_address": "",
            "headline": "",
            "generic": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "update_whitelist": [
                "full_name",
                "headline",
                "email_address",
                "external_reference",
                "linkedin_url",
                "bio",
                "website",
                "company_name",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip"
            ],
            "account_id": "",
            "id": "18603444"
        },
  "18603302": {
            "full_name": "",
            "photo_path": "",
            "email_address": "",
            "headline": "",
            "generic": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "update_whitelist": [
                "full_name",
                "headline",
                "email_address",
                "external_reference",
                "linkedin_url",
                "bio",
                "website",
                "company_name",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip"
            ],
            "account_id": "7600865",
            "id": "18603302"
        },
  "18603303": {
            "full_name": "",
            "photo_path": ",
            "email_address": "",
            "headline": "",
            "generic": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "update_whitelist": [
                "full_name",
                "headline",
                "email_address",
                "external_reference",
                "linkedin_url",
                "bio",
                "website",
                "company_name",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip"
            ],
            "account_id": "7600865",
            "id": "18603303"
        },
    "meta": {
        "count": 216,
        "page_count": 11,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }}
```

I have successfully pulled the data from the API, I just do not know how to iterate through each page in the API and append to the file.

Comment: Have you checked out the [official pagination support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support)?

Comment: yes but i dont really understand, i am new to ADF and APIs

Comment: Is the API publicly accessible so we can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: it is not. But it looks like this https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/users. I tried using {offset} as a query parameter with a range of 0:10000:1000 and it just took the data from the first page (20 users) and copied them in 1000 times. I don't know how to tell it to go to the next page

Comment: It would be hard for the community to answer if we don't have a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489735/azure-data-factory-pagination This is the answer^

Comment: Hi @jklein if you solved your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem